# How do I match an entire day to a datetime field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, datetime, select, timestamp

I have a table for matches. The table has a column named `matchdate`, which is a `datetime` field.

If I have 3 matches on 2011-12-01:

> - 2011-12-01 12:00:00
> - 2011-12-01 13:25:00
> - 2011-12-01 16:00:00

How do I query that? How do I query all matches on 1 single date?

I have looked at `date_trunc()`, `to_char()`, etc.
Isn't there some `"select * where datetime in date"` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast your [`timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) value to `date` if you want simple syntax. Like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  timestamp_col::date = '2011-12-01';  -- date literal
```

However, with big tables this will be faster:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  timestamp_col >= '2011-12-01 0:0'    -- timestamp literal
AND    timestamp_col <  '2011-12-02 0:0';
```

Reason: the second query does not have to transform every single value in the table and can utilize a simple index on the timestamp column. The expression is [sargable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable).

Note excluded the upper bound (`<` instead of `<=`) for a correct selection.
You can make up for that by creating an [index on an expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html) like this:

```sql
CREATE INDEX tbl_ts_date_idx ON tbl (cast(timestamp_col AS date));
```

Then the first version of the query will be as fast as it gets.

Comment: You can get Rails to produce the half-open `[2011-12-01, 2011-12-02)` version with `.where(:date => '2011-12-01' ... '2011-12-02')`, a 2-dot range would use `[2011-12-01, 2011-12-02]` and BETWEEN. Would PostgreSQL also cast everything to dates when using `>=` and `<` or would it be smart enough to know that casting the literals to timestamps would have the same effect and be less work?

Comment: @muistooshort: Postgres is smart enough in that case. That would result in my second query.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if i am missing something obvious here, but i think you can just

```
select * from table where date_trunc('day', ts) = '2011-12-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the SQL BETWEEN function like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '2011-12-01' AND '2011-12-02'
```

You may need to include times in the date literals, but this should include the lover limit and exclude the upper.

From rails I believe you can do:

```
.where(:between => '2011-12-01'..'2011-12-02')
```

Comment: You'd want `.where(:date => '2011-12-01' ... '2011-12-02')`: `:date` rather than `:between` and a triple-dot range to work with the half-open `[2011-12-01, 2011-12-02)` interval instead of a fully closed `[2011-12-01, 2011-12-02]` interval. The `..` does end up as a BETWEEN in the SQL, the `...` ends up using a `>=`/`<` pair.