# How to speed up the query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, windows, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have DB in PostgreSQL with a big data (now it is somewhere around 46 GB and the db will keep growing). I created indexes on often used columns and adapted the config file:

```
shared_buffers = 1GB
temp_buffers = 256MB
work_mem = 512MB
```

But this query is still slow:

```
select distinct us_category_id as cat, count(h_user_id) as res from web_hits 
inner join users on h_user_id = us_id 
where (h_datetime)::date = ('2015-06-26')::date and us_category_id != ''
group by us_category_id
```

Explain Analyze:

> ```
> HashAggregate (cost=2870958.72..2870958.93 rows=21 width=9) (actual time=899141.683..899141.683 rows=0 loops=1)
>
> Group Key: users.us_category_id, count(web_hits.h_user_id)
> -> HashAggregate (cost=2870958.41..2870958.62 rows=21 width=9) (actual time=899141.681..899141.681 rows=0 loops=1)
>
> Group Key: users.us_category_id
>  -> Hash Join (cost=5974.98..2869632.11 rows=265259 width=9) (actual time=899141.679..899141.679 rows=0 loops=1)
>
> Hash Cond: ((web_hits.h_user_id)::text = (users.us_id)::text)
> -> Seq Scan on web_hits (cost=0.00..2857563.80 rows=275260 width=7) (actual time=899141.676..899141.676 rows=0 loops=1)
> -> Seq Scan on web_hits (cost=0.00..2857563.80 rows=275260 width=7) (actual time=899141.676..899141.676 rows=0 loops=1)
> Filter: ((h_datetime)::date = '2015-06-26'::date)
>
> Rows Removed by Filter: 55051918
> -> Hash (cost=4292.99..4292.99 rows=134559 width=10) (never executed)
> -> Seq Scan on users (cost=0.00..4292.99 rows=134559 width=10) (never executed)
> Filter: ((us_category_id)::text <> ''::text)
>
> "Planning time: 1.309 ms"
> "Execution time: 899141.789 ms"
> ```

Date is changed.
How can I speed up the query?

Table and index creating

```
CREATE TABLE web_hits (
  h_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('w_h_seq'::regclass),
  h_user_id character varying,
  h_datetime timestamp without time zone,
  h_db_id character varying,
  h_voc_prefix character varying,
  ...
  h_bot_chek integer, -- 1-бот...
  CONSTRAINT w_h_pk PRIMARY KEY (h_id)
);
ALTER TABLE web_hits OWNER TO postgres;
COMMENT ON COLUMN web_hits.h_bot_chek IS '1-бот, 0-не бот';

CREATE INDEX h_datetime ON web_hits (h_datetime);
CREATE INDEX h_db_index ON web_hits (h_db_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
CREATE INDEX h_pref_index ON web_hits (h_voc_prefix COLLATE pg_catalog."default" text_pattern_ops);
CREATE INDEX h_user_index ON web_hits (h_user_id text_pattern_ops);

 CREATE TABLE users (
  us_id character varying NOT NULL,
  us_category_id character varying,
  ...
  CONSTRAINT user_pk PRIMARY KEY (us_id),
  CONSTRAINT cities_users_fk FOREIGN KEY (us_city_home)
      REFERENCES cities (city_id),
  CONSTRAINT countries_users_fk FOREIGN KEY (us_country_home)
      REFERENCES countries (country_id),
  CONSTRAINT organizations_users_fk FOREIGN KEY (us_institution_id)
      REFERENCES organizations (org_id),
  CONSTRAINT specialities_users_fk FOREIGN KEY (us_speciality_id)
      REFERENCES specialities (speciality_id),
  CONSTRAINT us_affiliation FOREIGN KEY (us_org_id)
      REFERENCES organizations (org_id),
  CONSTRAINT us_category FOREIGN KEY (us_category_id)
      REFERENCES categories (cat_id),
  CONSTRAINT us_reading_room FOREIGN KEY (us_reading_room_id)
      REFERENCES reading_rooms (rr_id)
);
ALTER TABLE users OWNER TO sveta;
COMMENT ON COLUMN users.us_type IS '0-аноним, 1-читатель, 2-удаленный';

CREATE INDEX us_cat_index ON users (us_category_id);
CREATE INDEX us_user_index ON users (us_id text_pattern_ops);
```

Comment: Just a note, you can remove the DISTINCT keyword because the result is already distinct thanks to your GROUP BY.

Comment: Please post table and indexes definition.

Comment: Can you detail your indexes that are already in place? Both tables look like they were accessed by seq scan.

Comment: I removed noise from your setup (default settings). On the other hand, important information is missing. Consider instructions in the tag info for [postgresql-performance](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). Why is one table owned by `postgres` and the other table by `sveta`? Any particular reason you use character data types for several ID columns instead of plain `integer` (or `bigint`)?

Comment: And why is `web_hits.h_user_id` not defined `NOT NULL`? Are there NULL values in the column? If yes, how do you intend to count those? It seems like there really should be a FK constraint from  `web_hits.h_user_id` to `users. us_id` ...

Comment: `Why is one table owned by postgres and the other table by sveta?` Just a typo, I fix it in the database. Not all ID is integer. And yes, `web_hits.h_user_id` can be NULL. I don't neet count their.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essential information is missing in the question. I am going to base parts of my answer on educated guesses.
`web_hits.h_user_id` is sometimes NULL, like you added in the comment.

### Query

Basically, the query can be simplified / improved to this in any case:

```
SELECT u.us_category_id AS cat, count(*) AS res
FROM   users    u
JOIN   web_hits w ON w.h_user_id = u.us_id
WHERE  w.h_datetime >= '2015-06-26 0:0'::timestamp
AND    w.h_datetime <  '2015-06-27 0:0'::timestamp
AND    w.h_user_id IS NOT NULL  -- remove irrelevant rows, match index
AND    u.us_category_id <> ''
GROUP  BY 1;
```

- `DISTINCT` is obviously unnecessary in an expensive way, since you already `group by us_category_id` (like [@Gordon already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31099666/939860)).
- Make the conditions [**sargable**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) so that an indexes can be used:

  - [How do I match an entire day to a datetime field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833046/how-do-i-match-an-entire-day-to-a-datetime-field/8833237#8833237)
- Since you have joined on the column `w.h_user_id`, it follows logically that resulting rows are `NOT NULL` in this column. `count(*)` is equivalent in this case and a bit faster.
- The condition `h_user_id IS NOT NULL` seems redundant since NULL is eliminated in the `JOIN` anyway, but it allows to use the partial index with matching condition (see below).
- `users.us_id` (and consequently `web_hits.h_user_id`) should probably not have the data type `varchar` (`character varying`). That's an inefficient data type for a PK / FK column in a huge table. Use a numeric data type like [`int` or `bigint`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) (or [`uuid`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-uuid.html) if you must).
  Similar considerations for `us_category_id`: should be `integer` or related.
- The standard SQL inequality operator is `<>`. Use that instead of the also supported `!=`.
- Use table qualification to avoid ambiguities - and in any case to make your query clear to the readers in a public forum.

#### Optimize

Further assuming that:

- `users.us_category_id <> ''` is true for most rows.
- Most or all rows with `web_hits.h_user_id IS NOT NULL` are counted.

Then this will be faster, yet:

```
SELECT u.us_category_id AS cat, sum(ct) AS res
FROM   users u
JOIN  (
   SELECT h_user_id, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   web_hits
   WHERE  h_datetime >= '2015-06-26 0:0'::timestamp
   AND    h_datetime <  '2015-06-27 0:0'::timestamp
   AND    h_user_id IS NOT NULL  -- remove irrelevant rows, match index
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) w ON w.h_user_id = u.us_id
AND    u.us_category_id <> ''
GROUP  BY 1;
```

### Indexes

Either way, [**partial indexes**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) are best for your case:

1.

```
CREATE INDEX wh_usid_datetime_idx ON web_hits(h_user_id, h_datetime)
WHERE  h_user_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Eliminate rows where `web_hits.h_user_id IS NULL` from the index.

Columns **in that order**, not the other way round like has been suggested. Detailed explanation:

- [Multicolumn index and performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33220/3684)

2.

```
CREATE INDEX us_usid_cat_not_empty_idx ON users(us_id)
WHERE  us_category_id <> '';
```

This will be considerably smaller, because we don't store the potentially lengthy `varchar` column `us_category_id` in the index - which we don't need for the case anyway. We just need to know it's `<> ''`. If you had `integer` columns this consideration would not apply.

And we also exclude rows with `''` or `NULL` in `us_category_id`, making the index smaller, yet.

You have to weigh maintenance cost for special indexes against their benefits. If you run queries with a matching condition a lot, it will pay, else, it might not, and more general indexes might be better overall.

---

Of course, all the usual advice on [performance optimization](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization) applies, too.

Frankly, there is not very much *right* about your query and many items are suspicious in your setup. Dealing with huge tables like you obviously are, you might consider professional help.

Comment: Unfortunately, `web_hits.h_user_id` can be NULL or have letter-value. But  otherwise you gave me detailed information, thats why thank you very much!

Comment: @Svetlana: Updated my answer to your update in the comment. Please remember to provide all relevant information in your next question.

Answer (score 2):

First, the distinct is not necessary:

```
select u.us_category_id as cat, count(h_user_id) as res
from web_hits h inner join
     users u
     on h.h_user_id = u.us_id 
where (h.h_datetime)::date = '2015-06-26'::date and
      u.us_category_id <> ''
group by u.us_category_id
```

Second, you want to remove the conversion on the column.  So:

```
select u.us_category_id as cat, count(h_user_id) as res
from web_hits h inner join
     users u
     on h.h_user_id = u.us_id 
where (h.h_datetime >= '2015-06-26' and h.h_datetime < '2015-06-27) and
      u.us_category_id <> ''
group by u.us_category_id;
```

Then, the following index should help the query:  `web_hits(h_datetime, h_user_id)`.  It might also be beneficial to have an index on `users(us_id, us_category_id)`.

Comment: Сonversion "::date" can not remove, because h_datetime have format yyyyMMdd dd:mm:ss

Comment: What is the datatype of h_datetime?

Comment: timestamp without time zone

Comment: Then you don't have to worry about the format.  A timestamp is essentially a floating point number.  Various clients display it various ways.

Comment: @DanBracuk: Actually, a `timestamp` is an `integer` representing 6 fractional digits internally in modern Postgres: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860.