# Comparing timestamps to epoch seconds

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, plpgsql, epoch, postgresql-9.5

In PostgreSQL 9.5 I have a table with 67000 records:

```
# \d words_nouns
           Table "public.words_nouns"
 Column  |           Type           | Modifiers 
---------+--------------------------+-----------
 word    | text                     | not null
 hashed  | text                     | not null
 added   | timestamp with time zone | 
 removed | timestamp with time zone | 
Indexes:
    "words_nouns_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (word)
Check constraints:
    "words_nouns_word_check" CHECK (word ~ '^[A-Z]{2,}$'::text)
```

And a similar table `words_verbs` with 36000 records.

Is it a good idea to define the following custom function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION words_get_added(
                in_visited integer,
                OUT out_json jsonb
        ) RETURNS jsonb AS
$func$
DECLARE
        _added text[];
BEGIN
        -- create array with words added to dictionary since in_visited timestamp
        IF in_visited > 0 THEN
                _added := (
                        SELECT ARRAY_AGG(hashed) 
                        FROM words_nouns 
                        WHERE EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM added) > in_visited
                        UNION
                        SELECT ARRAY_AGG(hashed) 
                        FROM words_verbs 
                        WHERE EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM added) > in_visited
                );

                IF  CARDINALITY(_added) > 0 THEN
                        out_json := jsonb_build_object('added', _added);
                END IF;
        END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

or should I better convert `in_visited` to a timestamp with timezone and compare to that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION words_get_added(
                in_visited integer,
                OUT out_json jsonb
        ) RETURNS jsonb AS
$func$
DECLARE
        _added text[];
BEGIN
        -- create array with words added to dictionary since in_visited timestamp
        IF in_visited > 0 THEN
                _added := (
                        SELECT ARRAY_AGG(hashed) 
                        FROM words_nouns 
                        WHERE added > TO_TIMESTAMP(in_visited)
                        UNION
                        SELECT ARRAY_AGG(hashed) 
                        FROM words_verbs 
                        WHERE added > TO_TIMESTAMP(in_visited)
                );

                IF CARDINALITY(_added) > 0 THEN
                        out_json := jsonb_build_object('added', _added);
                END IF;
        END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Below are 2 `EXPLAIN` outputs, but I am not sure how to interpret them:

```
# EXPLAIN SELECT ARRAY_AGG(hashed)
FROM words_nouns
WHERE EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM added) > 0
UNION
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(hashed)
FROM words_verbs
WHERE EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM added) > 0;
                                         QUERY PLAN                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=2707.03..2707.04 rows=2 width=32)
   ->  Sort  (cost=2707.03..2707.03 rows=2 width=32)
         Sort Key: (array_agg(words_nouns.hashed))
         ->  Append  (cost=1740.53..2707.02 rows=2 width=32)
               ->  Aggregate  (cost=1740.53..1740.54 rows=1 width=32)
                     ->  Seq Scan on words_nouns  (cost=0.00..1684.66 rows=22348 width=32)
                           Filter: (date_part('epoch'::text, added) > '0'::double precision)
               ->  Aggregate  (cost=966.45..966.46 rows=1 width=32)
                     ->  Seq Scan on words_verbs  (cost=0.00..936.05 rows=12157 width=32)
                           Filter: (date_part('epoch'::text, added) > '0'::double precision)
(10 rows)

# EXPLAIN SELECT ARRAY_AGG(hashed)
FROM words_nouns
WHERE added > to_timestamp(0)
UNION
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(hashed)
FROM words_verbs
WHERE added > to_timestamp(0);
                                           QUERY PLAN                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=2361.99..2362.00 rows=2 width=32)
   ->  Sort  (cost=2361.99..2361.99 rows=2 width=32)
         Sort Key: (array_agg(words_nouns.hashed))
         ->  Append  (cost=1517.06..2361.98 rows=2 width=32)
               ->  Aggregate  (cost=1517.06..1517.07 rows=1 width=32)
                     ->  Seq Scan on words_nouns  (cost=0.00..1517.05 rows=1 width=32)
                           Filter: (added > '1970-01-01 01:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone)
               ->  Aggregate  (cost=844.88..844.89 rows=1 width=32)
                     ->  Seq Scan on words_verbs  (cost=0.00..844.88 rows=1 width=32)
                           Filter: (added > '1970-01-01 01:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone)
(10 rows)
```

The question is: which of the 2 stored functions has better performance or do they not differ?

Comment: what's the question? :)

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question now. I wonder which of the 2 functions is faster and how to see it in the EXPLAIN outputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key factor for performance is an index that matches your query. Typically, you'd have an index on the plain column `added`, which should be matched with an input parameter of the same type, where the index is applicable.

For the task at hand, combine a plain index on `added` with your **second** function (`added > TO_TIMESTAMP(in_visited)`) - or a variation on the theme. The functional transformation happens before the value is compared to the column `added`, thus the expression is "sargable".

For top read performance you might have a multicolumn index on `(added, hashed)`, and keep your table vacuumed to allow index-only scans ...

Related:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)
- [How to speed up the query in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099515/how-to-speed-up-the-query-in-postgresql/31106856#31106856)
- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)