# Extract 30 minutes from timestamp and group it by 30 mins time interval -PGSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, datetime

In PostgreSQL I am extracting hour from the timestamp using below query.

```
select count(*) as logged_users, EXTRACT(hour from login_time::timestamp) as Hour 
from loginhistory 
where login_time::date = '2021-04-21' 
group by Hour order by Hour;
```

And the output is as follows

```
 logged_users | hour
--------------+------
           27 |    7
           82 |    8
          229 |    9
         1620 |   10
         1264 |   11
         1990 |   12
         1027 |   13
         1273 |   14
         1794 |   15
         1733 |   16
          878 |   17
          126 |   18
           21 |   19
            5 |   20
            3 |   21
            1 |   22
```

I want the same output for same SQL for 30 mins. Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the column on which you're aggregating to use the minute too:

```
select
  count(*) as logged_users,
  CONCAT(EXTRACT(hour from login_time::timestamp), '-', CASE WHEN EXTRACT(minute from login_time::timestamp) < 30 THEN 0 ELSE 30 END) as HalfHour 
from loginhistory 
where login_time::date = '2021-04-21' 
group by HalfHour
order by HalfHour;
```

Answer (score 3):

```sql
SELECT to_timestamp((extract(epoch FROM login_time::timestamp)::bigint / 1800) * 1800)::timestamp AS interval_30_min
     , count(*) AS logged_users
FROM   loginhistory
WHERE  login_time::date = '2021-04-21'  -- inefficient!
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Extracting the epoch gets the number of seconds since the epoch. Integer division truncates. Multiplying back effectively rounds down, achieving the same as `date_trunc()` for arbitrary time intervals.
1800 because 30 minutes contain 1800 seconds.
Detailed explanation:

- [Truncate timestamp to arbitrary intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730072/truncate-timestamp-to-arbitrary-intervals/12731753#12731753)

The cast to `timestamp` makes me wonder about the actual data type of `login_time`? If it's `timestamptz`, the cast depends on your current time zone setting and sets you up for surprises if that setting changes. See:

- [How do I match an entire day to a datetime field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833046/how-do-i-match-an-entire-day-to-a-datetime-field/8833237#8833237)
- [Subtract hours from the now() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894296/subtract-hours-from-the-now-function/30896121#30896121)
- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Depending on the actual data type, and exact definition of your date boundaries, there is a more efficient way to phrase your `WHERE` clause.